# Reversing string in a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
s = 'hello'
rev = ''

for char in s:
    rev = char + rev
return rev
```

Why does the for loop above add the characters in reverse? I tried using `rev += char` and it returned the string in the original order, `s`. This was mentioned in a video and they didn't explain properly, just said "Python's for loop over string doesn't work that way". I want to know why it does this, so in the future I will be more inclined to avoid these mistakes.

Another question is, can I implement this type of line in the for-loop over lists and will it output the reverse of the list? Since lists are mutable.

Comment: Because you're adding the character the the beginning of the list. Do `rev = rev + char` or simply `rev += char` (which means the same thing) instead.

Comment: Surely the *purpose* of this code is to reverse the string? Otherwise you would just `return s` directly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "Python's for loop over string doesn't work that way". It's just because you are doing `rev = ch + rev`, that is: iterating over every character and adding it at the beginning of `rev`.

Comment: On the first iteration you have `rev = "h" + ""` so `rev` is set to `"h"`. Then you have `rev = "e" + "h"` so `rev` is set to `"eh"` then you have `rev = "l" + "eh"` and `rev` becomes `"leh"` and so on.

Comment: Also, if you want to reverse the order, use string slicing `'hello'[::-1]` = `'olleh'`.  See [Strings and Character Data in Python](https://realpython.com/python-strings/). `['t', 'e', 's', 't'][::-1]` = `['t', 's', 'e', 't']` lists too.

Comment: For your second question, yes you could definitely reverse a list this way. Strings are lists of characters. It would be inefficient though, you should just do `reversed(my_list)` instead

Comment: @Boris no `str` objects are **not** lists of characters. There is no character type in Python, and while both `list` objects and `str` objects are *sequences*, that doesn't mean that `str` objects are lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop you have, your for loop is defined as:

```
s = 'happy'
rev = ''

for char in s:
    rev = ch + rev
```

If we look at this going through the first few iterations, we would get:
h
ah
pah
ppah
yppah

This is because as you update the variable rev, you are adding the next character (char) in front of rev through your definition.

rev = NEW CHARACTER + CURRENT REV
so looking at the final iteration, where we add y, you're adding:

rev = NEW CHARACTER (Y) + CURRENT REV (PPAH),
basically stating you are adding PPAH to the letter y, instead of adding y to PPAH.

The loop can be easily fixed by swapping ch and rev, making it:

```
for char in s:
    rev = rev + char
```

Answer (score 3):

The `+`-operator on strings means concatenation which is not commutative. So there's a difference between `char + rev` and `rev + char`.

Successively prepending the next character in front effectively reverses the string.